# Index versus ID in Rest API Design

Tags: json, api, rest, indexing, identifier

I finished some courses about REST API design in Python (FastAPI) and Javascript (NodeJS) and noticed, that identifiers are always stored inside the object, as in the following example:

```
Books = [
        {"ID": 1, "Title": "The Capital", "Author": "Karl Marx"},
        {"ID": 2, "Title": "The Wealth of Nations", "Author": "Adam Smith"},
        {"ID": 3, "Title": "Minima Moralia", "Author": "Theodor W. Adorno"}
        ]
```

When selecting a specific book, the backend has to iterate over the whole list to find the given id. I found that quite inefficient. I thought of using the index as identifier, since in my use-case the id is always index+1. The only downside that comes to my mind is, that the requester cannot force a specific id to an object.

I found it unintuitive that we dont use the index as identifier, when building a new system. No course covered that question. Maybe using the index as identifier is a bad idea. But i want to discuss it. Looking forward to hear more experienced answers.